# Is there any way to change pitch bend wheel values in real time?

Tags: keyboard, midi, vst, cubase

I have midi keyboard on repair (Evolution MK361-C) that has problems with Pitch Wheel. Pitch Wheel is not sendind accurate high values (7F as max) to computer, it sends maximum value of about 7A-7C.

I don't want to change potentiometer.

My question is: is there any VST plugin that will:

a) Replace values higher than 7A with 7F, so everything above 7A becomes 7F?

or

b) Narrow pitch wheel range, like, to leave 70% of range with same center?

Thank you for attention.

Comment: Cubase's Logical Editor or Input Transform could expand the values proportionally which would feel like less of a glitch. No doubt most of the high-end DAWs could do something similar. It's not really the thing a plugin would be built for, as DAWs already can.